# globalize my node variable express and route

Tags: node.js, express

Hello guys so i have this two variables i am requiring them for every route i have so i want to globalize them and just add them to the app.js but when i do that it didn't work.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

i tried to addd them in to my separate file config.js and then i require it in my route and assign it to variable and use it but it is not working.

my config file look like this

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express'),
  favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
  logger = require('morgan'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  methodOverride = require('method-override'),
  errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
  path = require('path');



module.exports = function() {
  var app = express();
var router = app.Router();


  return app;
}();
```

i get this error all the time : 
throw new Error('\'app.router\' is deprecated!\nPlease see the 3.x to 4.x migration guide for details on how to update your app.');

Comment: Have you tried not using app.Router() like the error says?

Comment: Also, requiring them in all of your routers is not really a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: Your `router` variable is an instance of Router, and **should** to be initialized inside each of your route files. I can appreciate trying to be as DRY as possible, but doing it this way will not work the way you expect it to. You can save a bit of typing by writing it this way:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
```

The longer explanation is that use multiple routes, you need a router for each route. This is to help break up the whole path associated with a request (i.e. `/bar/foo/baz`) into more manageable chunks.

Let's say your path can start with either `/cats` or `/dogs`. In the file where you declare all your middleware, you could write:

```
var catRoute = require(./routes/cats)
var dogRoute = require(./routes/dogs)

app.use('/cats', catRoute)
app.use('/dogs', dogRoute)
```

Then, inside `cats.js`:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/whiskers', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Cat whiskers!')
}
module.exports = router;
```

What this does is tell the app if it gets a path starting with `/cats`, use the cats route, which is just another piece of middleware. Within the route itself, we don't have to specify `/cats/whiskers`, only `/whiskers` because `app` is only passing down the part of the path **after** `/cats` to the cats.

You can nest as many routers as you want. Check out [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/keeping-api-routing-clean-using-express-routers) for a good example of how to do that.

Hypothetically, you could use only one router

Comment: thanks man what you wrote is perfectly right and it should work but i get an error `TypeError: Cyclic __proto__ value`
i am going to leave it so irritating code

Comment: Sounds like there's a circular dependency somewhere. You may need to restructure your code so you avoid having files that require each other. Don't give up! There can be a pretty steep learning curve with node, depending on your background.You can look at some sample apps on Github like [this](https://github.com/jbaumbach/nodejs-scaffolding) or look into something like [express generator](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express)